# Will I have to quarantine if traveling to the UK by Eurotunnel without exiting the car in France?

Tags: uk, quarantine, eurotunnel

Starting my journey to the UK from an exempt country, say, Germany, I will have to travel through France by car to get to the Eurotunnel. I would not stop, leave the car, take on any passenger, etc.

I don't know the exact procedure at the Eurotunnel.

Will I have to go into self isolation for 14 days according to the new rules for France (August 14th 2020)?

Are there any viable alternative ways to get me and my car to the UK from Germany without quarantine?

Comment: How do you get across a whole country on one tank of gas?  I can't even get across Texas on one tank of gas...

Comment: @Harper well, Germany to Calais is less than 400km. Maybe 4-5h of driving, half to 3/4 of a full tank. Definitely possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111841/discussion-on-question-by-donquikong-will-i-have-to-quarantine-if-traveling-to-t). The discussion had moved off topic, please only post clarification question comments here. All other comments are likely to be deleted.

Comment: It is about 200 miles from German border to Calais past the Netherlands and Belgium. France is a big country, but if you look on the map you will see that they only need to cover a very small bit of it so more than doable on a full tank.

Comment: Save your receipt from the petrol station in Germany, in case they suspect you of lying about stopping. This will give the amount and time of the purchase, which will bolster your case.

Answer (score 5):

Gov.uk says that if you travel from a country on the "exempt list" (and Germany is) and travel across one that is not on the list (e.g. France):

> You don’t need to self-isolate if you travel through a non-exempt
> country and you don’t stop in the country.
>
> If you do make a stop, you don’t need to self-isolate if:
>
> no new people get into the vehicle
> no-one in the vehicle gets out, mixes with other people, and gets in again
>
> You do need to self-isolate
> if you make a stop and:
>
> new people get into the vehicle, or
> someone gets out of the vehicle, mixes with other people and gets in again

[Coronavirus (COVID-19): travel corridors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors#countries-and-territories-with-no-self-isolation-requirement-on-arrival-in-england)

Comment: I drove from Germany to UK via Eurotunnel last night and quoted the above rule on the Passenger and Journey details form, in the bit where it asks whether you need to self isolate (and why not). Nobody asked about the form or about self isolation etc anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This post https://m.facebook.com/notes/british-embassy-paris/covid-19-update-transit-stops/3606924719365897/ (British embassy in Paris) says in Scenario 4:

No quarantine if you drive through France, do not get off your car and use the Eurotunnel without leaving your car.

As a side note, if you use the ferry you will have to get off your car and therefore self-isolate.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to drive through France without stopping if you take petrol in Germany. The process in Calais is that you do not interact with anyone apart from opening the window and passing the passports, so theoretically you do not need to self isolate. But, I am not a gov representative, so not sure how they interpret it. I think it is safer to do so than go to pubs in the UK. They are overcrowded and it is not fair to force reliable folk to self-isolate and at the same encourage others to mix with other people. It would be interesting to hear if it worked for you, so please update this later if you can.

Comment: Well, I wont try if I'm not sure, I can still cancel most of the trip and cut my losses if necessary. But I agree with the conclusion, it should be possible.

Comment: I did it without problems last night, please see my comment under the other answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158899/112535